# Parse Migration: Existing images not found

Tags: parse-platform, migration

I have migrated parse server and applications accessing it. However link to the files that were uploaded in parse previously give 403 (Forbidden).
When I open the file url in browser I get:

```
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <RequestId>60962746EA2AE731</RequestId>
    <HostId>Some long string of random characters here</HostId>
</Error>
```

Parse docs says if I provide proper fileKey the displaying of files will be taken care by Parse server itself. But I get 403 error for all the images in chrome console. Can someone help.

Comment: "section 5  Files"   in https://www.parse.com/migration   u need to address storage for the files that used to be in gridAdapter at api.parse.com.   see https://github.com/parse-server-modules/parse-files-utils  for help listing / migrating files

Comment: I am not talking about migration of files, but to access the existing files stored on Parse's S3 bucket. I resolved old issues but facing a new issue now. I have edited my question.

Comment: in a migrated app with media, using the old parse browser, i get the same message as u. BUT, the app works. The app , using master key,  can access the files stored to migrated instance of mongodb by a migrated instance of 'parse-server' running on my laptop.  To use the dashboard/data browser, you have need to migrate that too and run it off your new domain.

Comment: My problem here is if I run my express js application which is using my migrated parse server in backend, none of the images get loaded in the application. How can I resolve this before I migrate all the files?

Comment: I found the issue. I made a mistake in the fileKey while initialising Parse in server app. I have finalised the database migration now. Thanks for your answers.